# What does the extra "$()" in "$($())" selector do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement a jQuery scrollspy to one of the projects I am working on.

I found this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) which I managed to implement into my project. I wish to modify it but am stuck at trying to understand what this bit of code means.

```
var topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
   // Anchors corresponding to menu items
   scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
     var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
     if (item.length) { return item; }
});
```

I know in general, the code will search for all "a" links, find the href via the attr() function, and if it exists, add it into the map. What I don't understand is

```
 $($(this).attr("href"));
```

What does the extra $() selector mean? I understand that

```
$(this).attr("href");
```

means selecting/retrieving the href for this element. What does the $() do? Is it a nested selector? I tried googling but I couldn't find answers to it, or my google-fu is not up to par.

Also, does

```
$($(this).attr("href"));
```

only retrieve links in the following format index.html#section-one or #section-one?

**Update**

Also, how would '.length' determine if the element exists in the DOM? When I checked the console logs, a href link with 'index.html#section-one' would return a length of 0, while one with only '#section-one' would return with a length of 1. Why does that happen?

Comment: It wraps the string in jQuery object, in your case `#section-one` and then jQuery methods can be called on it

Comment: Hey Tushar, thanks for the really speedy reply!
If my understanding is correct, $($this).attr("href")); only retrieves the text after the # symbol?

Comment: No, it'll retrieve complete text of `href`

Comment: You should not use `href` to store reference, use `data-*` attributes and get it using `data()`. `$($(this).data('target')).css('color', 'green')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the `href` are anchor names (or fragment identifiers), which conveniently double as `id` selectors. By referencing the `href` attribute and then wrapping that with `$()`, you're effectively selecting an element with that `id`.

So, `<a href='#faq'>` would normally jump to an named anchor "faq", but by wrapping the attr value of `href`, you're selecting `$('#faq')`.

Comment: Thanks Jack. So if I have a `<a href="index.html#faq">` , would it be able to double as a id selector then? or would my id selector be 'index.html#faq' ?

Comment: Hey @JacobTan  - If you use `attr('href')`, then your selector would be `index.html#faq`, which wouldn't work. Instead, I would recommend using `.prop('hash')` and doing something like this: `$($(this).prop('hash'))`, which would return just the hash (or `#faq`) portion of your url.

Answer (score 3):

That code assumes that the `href` attribute is going to be an `id` reference, like `#about`. The outer `$()` goes ahead and grabs that `#about` element for you.

Comment: Not just `id`, **any selector**

Comment: You are right, but only an `id` would be a valid `href`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$($(this).attr("href"));
```

In above expression `$(this).attr("href")` will give **href attribute** of the specified html element which is string. If you want to convert this string to jQuery object and do further manipulation, you can achieve it using additional $() like

```
$($(this).attr("href"))
```